# Bootstrap wizard plugin - help on ajax saving per step/panel

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap wizard plugin on one of the bootstrap theme I got
https://github.com/gilluminate/Bootstrap-Wizard

And I'm trying to do an ajax submit on each of it's panels/steps but I can't seem to find where I should place the ajax submit code. So when you click on "next" the form fields on that panel should be saved.

Using PHP and JQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML `<script>` tag and put it inside of your page's head. Below is a super 'diluted' example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $('#name').on('submit', function() {

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <button id="name" name="name" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```